# How to create Web Deploy 2.0 projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, webdeploy

We are using Visual Studio 2010 to publish to IIS using Web Deploy.  I have now upgraded to Web Deploy 2.0 on the client, and the server (by uninstalling the old version and installing the new version).

From Visual Studio, it still seams to be creating web deploy 1.0 packages.  This is where I am confused.  How does Visual Studio integrate with Web Deploy?  How do I get Visual Studio to create Web Deploy 2.0 packages?

Comment: I found this "Unfortunately, if you install only the latest release this key does not exist and the script will fail." from http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html#fix_msdeploy_version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your post.

I just found a doc might help, it illustrates the installation and enabling of web deploy:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx

Moreover, I think web deploy is more relevant to ASP.Net, and if you can post another thread at:

http://forums.asp.net/26.aspx?Configuration+and+Deployment

I believe you can get more useful information.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I do have web deploy working correctly using web deploy 1.0.  The problem is how to get web deploy 2.0 working correctly from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  The batch file that was being generated by web deploy was checking for v1.1 in the registry.  Editing it to check for v2 works on a server that only has v2 installed.

After installing the Visual Studio service pack, I see now that the batch file is different, and no longer does a registry check so works with web deploy clients 1 and 2.

Comment: Which service pack are you referring to here?  I ended up adding the environment variable that points to Web Deploy and it would be nice to not have to do this.